# Auto resize UITextView in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have a question, how can I resize a textview in a scrollview and scrollview also must resize to be conformable with what size the textview will be.
Thank you.

Comment: I've experienced this same problem plenty of times, I'll update my answer if you need more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without auto layout it is much easier.  Just get the contentSize property of the UITextView:

```
float textViewHeight = textView.contentSize.height;
```

And then set scroll view content size according to the content size of the text view:

```
scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,textViewHeight + 100);
```

This will make the height of the scroll view the height of the content size of the textview plus 100 pixels (in case you have other stuff in your scroll view).

Comment: Thank you, sorry but i don't use layout, if you can help without layout.Thank you.

Comment: I've updated my answer for use without auto layout.  Let me know if that works.